# INSERT data on MySQL to specific position based on its value (similar to ORDER BY)

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns for simplicity sake:

```
Datename     |Date    |Name
-------------+--------+-----
30/06/15test |30/06/15|test
30/06/15other|30/06/15|other
```

**Note:** Column `Datename` is unique

I would like all new data to be inserted into the table based on its value.

Example:

- If the `Date` is `29/06/15`, it would be inserted at bottom of table.
- If the `Date` is `01/07/15`, it would be inserted at the top of the table

Or preferably sorted by `Datename` column so it will sort by date then name.

Is this easily achievable, or do I need to just create a page that `SELECT` and `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A table is, by definition, an unordered bag of rows. There is no guarantee that if you say `SELECT * FROM table` you will get the rows back in the same order you inserted. Think about throwing a bunch of popsicle sticks on the ground while blindfolded; now take off the blindfold and tell me which one hit the floor last.

No ORDER BY is essentially telling the database you don't care about order.

If you *do* care about order, you need two things:

1. At least one column that can dictate order (an auto increment column, a date/time column populated with now(), or something you manually specify).
2. An actual ORDER BY expression on the outermost part of the query that presents the data (and don't forget to include a tie-breaker, if the first column might not be unique).

Answer (score 1):

Check Codd's rules - there's no mention of "ordering". You can order by a PRIMARY KEY (in the SELECT statement) but you aren't forced to.

If you use ORDER BY in your SELECT for your INSERT and use MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT to INSERT into your target table, then you should have the target table's PK be "ordered" by your criteria.

You should be aware that the SQL standard doesn't specify an ordering unless the SELECT query specifies it. So, you could do SELECT * FROM My_Table (no order by) and get different results from two queries in a row (however, it does appear to me that this is implicitly ordered by PK by the RDBMS).

Comment: It's not implicitly ordered. It often is - but not always. Too many exceptions, to rely on it.

Comment: @ypercube - could you give a counterexample in any of the servers I mentioned? As I said, I've never seen it **not** happen - but I accept that it can - as it's not specified/guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had a SQLfiddle example. If I couldn't find the link, so here is another one: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f63e/1)

Comment: I thought that it only worked because the UNIQUE(b, a) was contrived - since by definition, PK(a) UNIQUE. Tried with your SQLFiddle - but then changed that to UNIQUE(b) and got same result -  the data was not in PK order. I'll be **! Even if you add the UNIQUE(b) after table creation **and** adding the data **and** doing a preliminary SELECT *... - it **still** returns the data out of PK order. Even more puzzling - create table, insert data select - in order of a. Then add Unique(b). In b order. Add PK(a) - still in b order - I thought it was the last one added, but apparently not. MySQL! :-)